# Can I embed struct into enum in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have code like this:

```rs
enum Packet {
    Quit,
    Message {
        text: String,
        time: i32,
        is_admin: bool,
    },
}
```

It's convenient, but I don't like having nested structs like this. Imagine if I needed more items in this enum, then the Packet definition would be too large.
So, is there a way for me to move the Message struct outside and just write its name somewhere in the definition of the Packet struct?
I thought about doing something like this:

```rs
struct ChatMessage {
    text: String,
    time: i32,
    is_admin: bool,
}
enum Packet {
    Quit,
    Message(ChatMessage),
}
```

*(btw can I name the struct the same as the item in Packet (`struct Message`, `Message(Message)`)?)*

But then I'd have to do `let msg = message.0` or something like that. If this is the only solution - I'm okay with that, but I'd be happy if there was a more concise solution.

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand your question. Both example are ok, don't worry about enum size.

Comment: @Stargateur I believe they meant size source-wise, aka the enum definition becomes long and somewhat unwieldy as the number of struct-like variants increases, as each field of the variant adds one line to the enum definition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It's convenient, but I don't like having nested structs like this.

It is not a nested struct, it's a struct-like variant.

> So, is there a way for me to move the Message struct outside and just write its name somewhere in the definition of the Packet struct? I thought about doing something like this:

You can do exactly that, it works as-is, it's a very common pattern.

> (btw can I name the struct the same as the item in Packet (struct Message, Message(Message))?)

Yes, there is literally no relationship between the two: `Packet::Message` is a constructor for the `Packet` enum, and `Message` is an unrelated (but embedded) type.

> But then I'd have to do let msg = message.0 or something like that.

Yes and no, enums require pattern matching of some sort, so in all cases you have to match your `Packet` variants. With the first version you extract the variant's fields directly:

```rust
match packet {
    Quit => todo!("something"),
    Message { text, .. } => todo!("something with {}", text)
}
```

while with the second you extract the `Message`, and from there its content:

```rust
match packet {
    Quit => todo!("something"),
    Message(m) => todo!("something with {}", m.text)
}
```

However patterns have effectively unlimited "depth" so you can do both at once just fine, it's just a bit more verbose:

```rust
match packet {
    Quit => todo!("something"),
    Message(ChatMessage { text, .. }) => todo!("something with {}", text)
}
```

demo (incomplete): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b2bdaf08c45424f507955790445cc2f9