# Make an Enum from struct

Tags: rust, struct, discriminated-union

I want to make an enum from a struct.

The definitions:

```rust
struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
}

enum Message {
    Move { x: u8, y: u8 },
    nothing,
}
```

So if I have instantiated a `Point` in my code, how can I make a `Message` from the struct?

I've tried this code:

```rust
Message::Move(Point { x: 10, y: 15 })
```

But this code throws an error saying

```
error[E0423]: expected function, tuple struct or tuple variant, found struct variant `Message::Move`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I embed struct into enum in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70682771/can-i-embed-struct-into-enum-in-rust)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your enum variant can simply contain an instance of the struct.

```
enum Message {
  Move(Point),
  NoMessage,
}
```

Then the syntax you wanted will work as-is.

```
Message::Move(Point { x: 10, y: 15 })
```